# Spring Data Cassandra not mapping JSON Request if key of POJO is composite

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra, spring-boot-test

I am trying to save a request to Data Stax-Cassandra.
Components:
EventController:@RestEndPoint
OneKeyClass:For Complex Key(with multiple columns)
I am using Standard Spring Repository Model to save and fetch the data.

```
Gradle:
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "1.5.3.RELEASE"
}

apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
    baseName = 'sample-boot-with-cassandra'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka')
        compile('org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test')


    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

***Controller:***

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.company.employee.model.Event;
import com.company.employee.service.EventService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/event")
public class EventController {

    @Autowired
    private EventService eventService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Event> saveEvent(@RequestBody Event event){
        return new ResponseEntity<Event>(eventService.saveEvent(event), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

***EventServiceImpl***

```
package com.company.employee.service;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.company.employee.model.Event;
import com.company.employee.model.LoginEvent;
import com.company.employee.repository.EventRepository;
import com.company.employee.repository.LoginEventRepository;

@Service
public class EventServiceImpl implements EventService {
    private EventRepository eventRepository;

    private LoginEventRepository loginEventRepository;
    private Logger logger=LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
     public EventServiceImpl(EventRepository eventRepository,LoginEventRepository loginEventRepository) {
         this.eventRepository=eventRepository;
         this.loginEventRepository=loginEventRepository;
     }

    @Override
    public Event saveEvent(Event event) {
        logger.info("saving event"+event.toString());
        return eventRepository.save(event);
    }

    @Override
    public LoginEvent saveEvent(LoginEvent event) {
        return loginEventRepository.save(event);
    }

}
```

***Repository:***

```
package com.company.employee.repository;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository;

import com.company.employee.model.Event;

public interface EventRepository extends CassandraRepository<Event> {

}
```

***Event:***

```
package com.company.employee.model;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

@Table(value="event")
public class Event {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Event [eventKey=").append(eventKey).append(", transactionstatus=").append(transactionstatus)
                .append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    @PrimaryKey
    private EventKey eventKey;

    public EventKey getEventKey() {
        return eventKey;
    }

    public void setEventKey(EventKey eventKey) {
        this.eventKey = eventKey;
    }

    public String getTransactionstatus() {
        return transactionstatus;
    }

    public void setTransactionstatus(String transactionstatus) {
        this.transactionstatus = transactionstatus;
    }

    @Column(value="transactionstatus")
    private String transactionstatus;
}
```

***EventKey***
    package com.company.employee.model;

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.cassandra.core.Ordering;
import org.springframework.cassandra.core.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKeyClass;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;

@PrimaryKeyClass
public class EventKey implements Serializable {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("EventKey [eventsource=").append(eventsource).append(", eventid=").append(eventid)
                .append(", eventstate=").append(eventstate).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + eventid;
        result = prime * result + ((eventsource == null) ? 0 : eventsource.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((eventstate == null) ? 0 : eventstate.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        EventKey other = (EventKey) obj;
        if (eventid != other.eventid)
            return false;
        if (eventsource == null) {
            if (other.eventsource != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!eventsource.equals(other.eventsource))
            return false;
        if (eventstate == null) {
            if (other.eventstate != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!eventstate.equals(other.eventstate))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    public String getEventsource() {
        return eventsource;
    }
    public void setEventsource(String eventsource) {
        this.eventsource = eventsource;
    }
    public EventKey(String eventsource, int eventid, String eventstate) {
        super();
        this.eventsource = eventsource;
        this.eventid = eventid;
        this.eventstate = eventstate;
    }
    public int getEventid() {
        return eventid;
    }
    public void setEventid(int eventid) {
        this.eventid = eventid;
    }
    public String getEventstate() {
        return eventstate;
    }
    public void setEventstate(String eventstate) {
        this.eventstate = eventstate;
    }
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name="eventsource",ordinal=0,type=PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String eventsource;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name="eventid",ordinal=1,type=PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED,ordering=Ordering.ASCENDING)
    private int eventid;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name="eventstate",ordinal=2,type=PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED,ordering=Ordering.ASCENDING)
    private String eventstate;


}
```

***Error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target bean must not be null!***

saving eventEvent [**eventKey=null**, transactionstatus=success]

Incoming Payload:

```
{
  "eventsource" : "terminal",
  "eventid": "23232",
  "eventstate" : "CI",
  "transactionstatus" : "success"
}
```

I followed
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/cassandra.core.html

Thanks in advance for looking and trying to help.

Comment: Please include the full stack trace.

Comment: please find pastebin   https://pastebin.com/wBzZLhMb

Answer (score 1):

The JSON payload does not match your object structure. Your JSON representation should rather match:

```
{
  "eventKey": {
    "eventsource" : "terminal",
    "eventid": "23232",
    "eventstate" : "CI"
  },
  "transactionstatus" : "success"
}
```

Alternatively, you could inline `EventKey` into `Event` or use two different data structures, one for the API the other one to store and query your data in Cassandra. IMHO splitting responsibilities is the better option to keep things decoupled although using the same types to represent your data through your API and in its persistent form requires less code and no mapping.

Comment: yeah that is true.I was giving wrong json.Also both POJO need default constuctors otherwise jackosn won't be able to map the json to class